# Ошибки "Opening and ending tag mismatch" при чтении XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Есть структура:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<all>
     <met>
       <title>Кредитный калькулятор для онлайн займов</title><meta name="description" content=""/>
     </met>
     <links>
        <a href="http://easy/bistrie-zaymi-na-kartu-bistro-v-sterlitamake/kreditnie-brokeri-v-kanske.html">Кредитные брокеры В Канске</a>             
        <a href="http://easy/denjgi-v-zaymi-na-kartu-v-viborge/vozjmu-denjgi-v-dolg-v-novoshahtinske.html">Возьму деньги в долг В Новошахтинске</a>
     </links>
     <pagination>
        <a href='0'>Номер 0</a><br><a href='1'>Номер 1</a><br><a href='2'>Номер 2</a><br>
        <a href='3'>Номер 3</a><br><a href='4'>Номер 4</a><br><a href='5'>Номер 5</a><br>
     </pagination>
     <key>Кредитный калькулятор для онлайн займов</key>
</all>
```

Пытаюсь загрузить и достать все данные из `<links></links>`.

```
$file = simplexml_load_file("cache/easy/main.xml");
echo $file->links->asXml();
```

Но в результате получаю сообщения об ошибках

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): cache/easy/main.xml:21: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 20 and pagination in E:\OpenServer\domains\easy\test.php on line 2
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): </pagination><key>Кредитный калькулятор  для онла in E:\OpenServer\domains\easy\test.php on line 2
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in E:\OpenServer\domains\easy\test.php on line 2
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): cache/easy/main.xml:21: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 20 and pagination in E:\OpenServer\domains\easy\test.php on line 2
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): </pagination><key>Кредитный калькулятор для онла in E:\OpenServer\domains\easy\test.php on line 2
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in E:\OpenServer\domains\easy\test.php on line 2
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): cache/easy/main.xml:21: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 19 and all in E:\OpenServer\domains\easy\test.php on line 2

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): дитный калькулятор для онлайн займов</key></all> in E:\OpenServer\domains\easy\test.php on line 2
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in E:\OpenServer\domains\easy\test.php on line 2
```

... и тому подобное

Comment: Как мне известно, то Вам надо входить в родительский тэг, из-за этого он не может распарсить данную строку.

Comment: Теги `br` надо закрывать, иначе это невалидный `xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не валидный XML файл. Для тега `br` отсутствует закрывающий. О чем собственно и сообщает парсер в своих предупреждениях.

Замените `<br>` на `<br />`

Comment: Можете добавить в ответ: для проверки XML можно сохранить xml в файл например `test.xml` и посмотреть его в браузере.... тем самым если будут ошибки - можно его исправить........... что-то типа того)